# Alternating incremental for loop

Tags: loops, for-loop, math

I'm stuck on how to make a for loop that will alternate increments in a series. For example:

```
i          x
2.       7
3.       12
4.        14
```

Where x is some combination of i. It first increments by 5, and then by 2 and then back to 5. I've tried using modulus to start an alternating series, but I can't seem to get the number to increase. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: It would be helpful if you also tagged which programming language you're working with (unless you're simply asking about pseudocode).

Comment: I'm working mostly in Java right now, but I just thought pseudocode would be easier to answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it have to be a for loop? There's still the while loop.

```
int i = 0;  
char switcher = 0; /*in this case it could also be a bool.*/  
while(some statement)  
{  
    switch(switcher)  
    {  
    case 0:  
        i+=5;  
        break;  
    case 1:  
        i+=2;  
        break;  
    }  
    switcher++;  
    if(switcher > 1)  
        switcher = 0;  
     //do something  
}
```

You could easily add more different increments to that code.

Comment: Or `switcher = (switcher + 1) % 2;`

Answer (score 0):

It'd be best to use a while loop with a flag that keeps track of whether or not you need to increment by 2 or 5.

```
incrementFlag = true;
while(someCondition)
{
   [code...]


   if (incrementFlag)
      i += 5;
   else
      i+=2

   incrementFlag = !incrementFlag; // Alternate incrementing
}
```